# Syncing time on two networked machines

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, permissions, time

I'm trying to sync the clocks on a Windows 7 (A) and a Windows 8.1 (B) computer on their own, private network by using the command (cmd on `computerA`):

```
net time \\computerB /set /y
```

As I expect, this command gives me an access denied error, since the local administrator account on `computerA` doesn't have permission to `computerB`.

I would like to set up an account, or allow `Everyone` or `Guest` permission on a specific area of `computerB`, so that this  time sync can occur properly. Unfortunately, I can't seem to find any documentation about permissions related to this command, and because of that, I'm working under the assumption that this command will require administrative privileges on both machines.

This network is completely offline, and for all intents and purposes, it's comprised of only these two machines. I would ideally like to have a time sync happen without adding additional accounts on the machines or computers/servers on this network.

Is this possible to do with net time, and if not, is there another way that I can sync computerB's time onto computerA over this offline network?

Answer (score 0):

Windows considers the clock a high-security setting (due to its use in TLS, Kerberos, and Event Logs) – allowing to change it over the network, anonymously, might not be wise.

That said, access to change the clock is granted by [SeSystemTimePrivilege](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn221970(v=ws.11).aspx), which can be given to arbitrary users via Group Policy or directly via `secpol.msc` (under Local Policies → User Privilege Assignment).

[image]

Comment: I'm able to change the time on the Windows 7 machine as administrator, my question is related to the permissions needed to query a remote machine for the time to use with `net time`. Will modifying this GPO allow remote users to query this server successfully? I'm not worried about security on this network, since it's only 2 computers without external internet access.